# Python Pandas If Else Return multiple values DataFrame value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to do the following:

1. Pass Dataframe[['ID']['Team'] to function
2. If Team is Blue, return    'Y' to 'Can he play?' and also return the
           value 'Blue' to 'Why?'

Below is my attempt at the code.

```
def play(df):
if df['Team'] in list(['Blue']):
    return 'Exclude','**************'  

df['Can he play?'],df['Why?'] = df.apply(play, axis = 1)
```

I do not know how to return the dataframe value from the conditional statement

How do I return 'Blue' (the value in df['Team'])

[image]

Comment: Hi there. When posting Python code please take care to make sure your indentation is correctly formatted. You can copy/paste your exact code into the edit form, select it, and press Ctrl-K to indent it all at once.

Comment: I'm really confused why you wrote `if df["Team"] in list["Blue"])`. First of all `["Blue"]` is already a (single element) list, so wrapping that in `list()` just makes a useless copy of it. But second, why not just `if df["Team"] == "Blue"`?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two steps, like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': ['Blue', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Red']})
colour = 'Blue'
df['Can he play?'] = np.where(df['Team'] == colour, 'Y', None)
df['Why?'] = np.where(df['Team'] == colour, colour, None)

    Team Can he play?  Why?
0   Blue            Y  Blue
1  Green         None  None
2   Blue            Y  Blue
3    Red         None  None
```